# Errors encountered during installation of fairseq

Tags: installation, fairseq

I have tried various methods to install fairseq, but still reported an error in the Windows system. I hope someone can answer this question
`
Building wheel for fairseq (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for fairseq (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [14 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
copying fairseq\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\fairseq
running build_ext
skipping 'fairseq/data\data_utils_fast.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'fairseq/data\token_block_utils_fast.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'fairseq.libbleu' extension
"D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -ID:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\include -ID:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\Include "-ID:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-ID:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" /EHsc /Tpfairseq/clib/libbleu/libbleu.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\fairseq/clib/libbleu/libbleu.obj -std=c++11 -O3
cl: 命令行 warning D9002 :忽略未知选项“-std=c++11”
cl: 命令行 warning D9002 :忽略未知选项“-O3”
libbleu.cpp
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\yvals.h(17): fatal error C1083: 无法打开 包括文件: “crtdbg.h”: No such file or directory
error: command 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for fairseq
Failed to build fairseq
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fairseq, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

`

I have tried various methods to install fairseq, but still reported an error in the Windows system. I hope someone can answer this question